# what to do with an inverted polymorphic relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been trying to get my head around these polymorphic relationships all day. I might be over complicating/thinking it but.  Can Laravel handle inverse polymorphic relationships? I have a registration flow that can have two types of field Models- normal field and customField.

When I loop through all the fields available it could pull the attributes from either NormalField or CustomField.

```
<?php 
    foreach($registrationFlow->fields->get() as $field)
    {
        echo $field->name; // could be custom field or could be normal field
    }
?>
```

My difficulty is that, [the example given](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) in the docs works if you want to assign a photo to either staff or orders, but i want to assign either a customField or a normalField to a registrationFlow

***Edit**

If you follow the [example for the polymorphic many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations), The tag class contains posts and videos- while i would want just a simple fields() method that relates to customField or normalField dependent on the type

Comment: I don't understand the difference? I'm not sure what you mean by an 'inverted polymorphic relationship', could you be more clear?

Comment: if you follow the official example i would want something like $photos->items - i think writing this answer has got it clearer in my head

Comment: i think i have explained it better

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should take a look at the updated docs for Laravel 5.1: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations.

I think the difficulty with the example they provide is that the relationship between `Photo` and `Staff`/`Product` are "has-a" relationships, whereas you are trying to model an "is-a" relationship.  However, you can model "is-a" essentially the same way.  Take a look at this article: http://richardbagshaw.co.uk/laravel-user-types-and-polymorphic-relationships/.

Basically, the strategy is to define a generic model (and a generic table), perhaps in your case `Field`, that relates to your `RegistrationFlow`.  You then have two subtype models, `NormalField` and `CustomField`, that have one-to-one relationships with `Field`.  (there's your "is-a").  Thus, `RegistrationFlow` is *indirectly* related to your field subtypes.

Polymorphism comes in when you want to access the specific subtypes:

```
class Field extends Model {

    public function fieldable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Your base `field` table should have `fieldable_id` and `fieldable_type` columns defined (see the Eloquent docs).

You can then add methods to `NormalField` and `CustomField` that let you access the base model (your "inverse relationship"):

```
class NormalField {  

    public function field()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Field', 'fieldable');
    }
}

class CustomField {  

    public function field()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Field', 'fieldable');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$field = Field::find(1);

// Gets the specific subtype
$fieldable = $field->fieldable;
```